# How to add queried rows with same values?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP. I have a table that stores the transactions bought. I am to summarize the transactions that happens in between two dates. For example: 2014-03-21 to 2014-03-23
I'm placing this in a fpdf :)

Here's my query:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_items INNER JOIN tbl_receipts ON tbl_items.item_id=tbl_receipts.item_id WHERE receiptdate >= '$sdate' && receiptdate <='$ldate'  ORDER BY tbl_items.item_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$addtotal = 0;
$counter = 1;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $totaladd = $row['quantity_bought'] * $row['itemquantity_price'];
        $item = $row['item_description'];
        $num = $row['quantity_bought'];
        $pdf->Cell(15, 13, '', 0, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(15, 6, $counter, 1, 0, 'R');
        $pdf->Cell(60, 6, $row['item_description'], 1, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(20, 6, $row['quantity_bought'], 1, 0, 'R');
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $row['itemquantity_price'], 1, 0, 'R');
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, "$totaladd.00", 1, 0, 'R');
        $pdf->Ln(6);
        $addtotal = $addtotal + $totaladd;
        $counter++;
    }
}
$pdf->Cell(15, 15, '', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(15, 6, '', 1, 0, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(60, 6, 'SUB-TOTAL', 1, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, '', 1, 0, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, '', 1, 0, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, "$addtotal.00", 1, 0, 'R');

$pdf->Ln(4);
?>
```

However, after summarizing, I have multiple rows for items with same item_description. I want to add those item quantities to avoid repetition. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I pass by the array, or I accumulate on the key and then I browse the array.

for example:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $array[$row['item_description']]['quantity_bought'] = $row['quantity_bought'];
     $array[$row['item_description']]['itemquantity_price'] = $row['itemquantity_price'];
     ...   

}

foreach($array as $item_description => $array_detail){
     $item = $item_description;
     foreach($array_detail as $key => $value){
            if ($key == 'quantity_bought')  $num = $value;
            ...
        }
    }
```